# Change Segmented Control inner padding iOS 13

Tags: swift, xcode, segmentedcontrol

`UISegmentedControl` looks great in iOS 13 and the animations it provides are awesome but I need to increase the *inner padding* to match my design.

What I have (font is already set in code):

[image]

How it should look (ideally):

[image]

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Taking a quick look, I expect you'll run into trouble trying to modify that on a default `UISegmentedControl`. You may want to look at [TOSegementedControl](https://github.com/TimOliver/TOSegmentedControl) ... it has a "Thumb Inset" property that may give you just what you want.

Comment: Looks like a great way to achieve this, thanks!